# How to manage UITouch events on UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitouch

I have an issue not resolved yet related to video embeding into PDF file.

I'm having UIWebView object on scrollView.

sample code:

```
        NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.funmazacontent.com/mobilemp4/Abhi%20Abhi%20-%20Jo%20Hum%20Chahein%20%5BFunmaza.com%5D.mp4"];
       _videoWebView = [[CustomWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 10, 570, 300) andUrl:url];
       [scrollView addSubview:_videoWebView];
```

How can we restrict touch events for UIScrollview to activate webview touch events.
Please observe the attached screenShot.[image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you add any view to a UIScrollView, the events of the scrollView gets called automatically. So, i suggest you to add your `_videoWebView` to the parent of UIScrollView.

```
 NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.funmazacontent.com/mobilemp4/Abhi%20Abhi%20-%20Jo%20Hum%20Chahein%20%5BFunmaza.com%5D.mp4"];
   _videoWebView = [[CustomWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 10, 570, 300) andUrl:url];
   [parentView addSubview:_videoWebView];
```

Here **parentView** refers to what ever is the parent of the UIScrollView. for example, if you have added UIScrollView to a view called **testView**, then add the _videoWebView also to the same **testView** and check it. It should work.

Comment: Ya, you're right. But i need to zoom the entire scrollview with webView also. Is it possible like you suggest?

Comment: i am not sure about that. But, try doing what ever i said and check for yourself :)